# Bash - call command recursively on all files in a directory

Tags: bash, recursion

I have a directory called `Original`, which contains flac files (all with the extension *flac) contained within various folders for album & artist), e.g. `Original/ABBA/Arrival/02 Dancing Queen.flac`.

Using Bash, I would like to run the `flac -d` command on those files, with the output set to a new parent directory (`Raw`), but with the same child directories & filename as the input file, e.g. the full command would be:

```
flac -d 'Original/ABBA/Arrival/02 Dancing Queen.flac' -o 'Raw/ABBA/Arrival/02 Dancing Queen.wav'
```

But I would like this command to be run on every flac file within the 'Original' directory - recursively.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't see any questions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

simple and short

```
shopt -s globstar
ls ** | grep flac$
```

you can put it in a for loop and do what ever you want to do with it

Comment: See [Why you don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` to list the files recursively. Use its `-name` filter to only get the `flac` files.

Use `exec` to run a command for each file found. `{}` expands the the file path, you can use bash's Prameter Expansion to remove `Original` from the beginning and `flac` from the end of each filepath.

```
find Original -name '*.flac' -exec bash -c \
    'o="{}" ; r=Raw${o#Original} ; r=${r%flac}wav ; flac -d "$o" -o "$r"' \;
```

As file paths can contain spaces, don't forget to doublequote the variables.

If your paths contain double quotes, you're doomed.